# Problems linking to POCO libraries in ARM Linux crosscompile environment

Tags: linux, linker, arm, poco

I have a problem porting POCO 1.4.6p2 to ARM based platform. I have successfully maked all the POCO libraries and installed those using cross-compiling and a ToolChain from Karo Electronics for their TX28 board (http://www.karo-electronics.com/tx28.html).
However when I try to link to any of the dynamic release POCO libraries, f. ex. libPocoFoundation.so I get link errors like this:

> Linking CXX executable hellodingo
>   /home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/lib/libPocoFoundation.so: undefined reference to `Poco::Channel::setProperty(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
>   /home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/lib/libPocoFoundation.so: undefined reference to`Poco::LoggingRegistry::channelForName(stlp_std::basic_string, stlp_std::allocator > const&) const'
>   /home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/lib/libPocoFoundation.so: undefined reference to `Poco::SystemException::SystemException(std::string const&, int)'
>   /home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/lib/libPocoFoundation.so: undefined reference to`Poco::RegularExpressionException::RegularExpressionException(std::string const&, int)'
>   ...

However if I link instead to the dynamic debug version of the POCO libraries, f.ex. libPocoFoundationd.so, everything links without a problem.

This is also true if I try to build the POCO libraries and do not omit PageCompiler,PageCompiler/File2Page which are executables needing PocoFoundation and more POCO libraries.

I'm using version gcc and g++ version 4.7.2 (the cross compiler).
I'm using the STLport v. 5.2.1 when building the POCO libraries.

What can be causing this link-difference between the release and debug version of the POCO libraries?

PS: Even when using the debug version of the POCO libs when I add more libraries than just the foundation (for example the PocoZip library) , I start getting the same errors from PocoZip complaining about undefined reference from PocoZip to items in PocoFoundatoin.

Below is a CMAkeLists.txt that I use for building:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/armsdk/projects/Toolchain-TX28.cmake)

project(hellodingo) 

add_executable(hellodingo SmoDeviceI2C.cpp tca6424a.cpp main.cpp) 

include_directories(/home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/include)

add_library(STLport SHARED IMPORTED)
add_library(PocoFoundation SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(STLport PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/armsdk/projects/STLport/install/arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi-lib/libstlport_arm-linux-gcc.so")
set_target_properties(PocoFoundation PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/lib/libPocoFoundationd.so")
set_target_properties(PocoUtil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/armsdk/projects/poco/install/lib/libPocoUtild.so")

target_link_libraries(hellodingo STLport PocoFoundation PocoUtil)

install(TARGETS hellodingo RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: I'd run the (cross) objdump on the libraries, probably with the -T flag, to figure out what is actually implemented in the final version of them.  Perhaps you have the wrong settings for retaining (locally) "unused" functions and they are getting stripped out.

Comment: Yes the dump is different between the debug and release version. Both version have a lot of "*UND*" lines (I assume this means "undefined"). However the DEBUG version is only having such lines refering to STL library calls, while the RELEASE version has both STL library calls as well as some of its own routine reference. So it seems you are right. How do I force the compiler to retain unused functions?

Comment: The problem is solved. Se solution at http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=6048&p=10786#p10786